# MySQL: count no duplicates of another column when using UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum, union

The following query works great to count and get the total sum of visitors to my page.

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) AS count
FROM visits
WHERE status <> 'test'
GROUP BY id

UNION ALL

SELECT 'SUM' id, COUNT(id)
FROM visits
WHERE status <> 'test'
```

But inside the visits table I have a column called IP where I store the IP of the visitors. I want to change the above query so that visits with the same IP are not counted (I only want to count unique IPs). How can I do it?

I have tried `HAVING COUNT(IP) > 1` but it doesn't work.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Maybe you want to `count(distinct IP)`

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT IP)` instead of `COUNT(ID)`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count

Comment: thanks! it worked! How can I accept the answer in a comment?